# Use a class decorator to implement late-initialization

Tags: python, decorator, lazy-initialization

I am using some classes which need to connect to databases. The connection is only really needed when performing a real action. I want to delay the connection phase until it is really needed. For that, I want to do something similar to this:

```
class MyClass

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None

    def connect(self):
        if self.conn : return
        self.conn = ConnectToDatabase()

    @connect
    def do_something1(self):
        self.conn.do_something1()

    @connect
    def do_something2(self):
        self.conn.do_something2()
```

But I do not know how to define the `connect` decorator for the class.

I could of course do something like this:

```
    def do_something1(self):
        self.connect()
        self.conn.do_something1()
```

But using decorators seems a more readable solution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than trying to decorate the functions that require connections, use a property for getting the connection itself.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._conn = None

    @property
    def conn(self):
        if self._conn is None:
            self._conn = ConnectToDatabase()
        return self._conn

    def do_something1(self):
        self.conn.do_something1()

    def do_something2(self):
        self.conn.do_something2()
```

As for a straight decorator example, playing off F.J's answer:

```
def prerequisite(prerequisite_function, *pre_args, **pre_kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            prerequisite_function(self, *pre_args, **pre_kwargs)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper

 class MyClass(object):

     def __init__(self):
         self.conn = None

     def connect(self):
         if self.conn is None:
             self.conn = ConnectToDatabase()

     @prerequisite(connect)
     def do_something(self):
         self.conn.do_something()
```

You could also make `prerequisite` more robust by making it create descriptors so that it can behave correctly for functions and static methods as well as class and instance methods.

Comment: If you ever stop learning, you are obsolete and will be replaced with a newer model.

Answer (score 2):

I do like sr2222's approach of using a property for getting the connection, however here is an approach with decorators which may be useful or at least informative (use of `functools.wraps()` is optional):

```
import functools

def require_connection(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.connect()
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None

    def connect(self):
        if self.conn : return
        self.conn = ConnectToDatabase()

    @require_connection
    def do_something1(self):
        self.conn.do_something1()

    @require_connection
    def do_something2(self):
        self.conn.do_something2()
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but looks interesting. Nevertheless, sr2222 reply does in a simpler way what I wanted to do, and although this is directly replying to my question, I prefer the other solution.

Comment: Why even make that a method on the class?  `require_connection` is going to be available yet confusingly useless/broken at any point after the class has been created.  Either make it a straight helper function or make it more meaningful with a metaclass.

Comment: @sr2222 Good point, I moved `require_connection` out of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to sr2222's solution, but calling it what it is: a `cached_property`.

The code is more compact, uses reusable building blocks, and in my opinion more readable.

```
class MyClass(object):

    @cached_property
    def conn(self):
        return ConnectToDatabase()

    def do_something1(self):
        self.conn.do_something1()

    def do_something2(self):
        self.conn.do_something2()
```

The definition of `cached_property` is found [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Cached_Properties).

Comment: The `property` decorator is a built-in though, while `cached_property` is not.

Comment: correct. it is still a very useful building block.  grab it once, use it plenty.