# Tricks to improve performance of python backend

Tags: python, performance, resources

I am using python programs to nearly everything:

- deploy scripts
- nagios routines
- website backend (web2py)

The reason why I am doing this is because I can reuse the code to provide different kind of services.

Since a while ago I have noticed that those scripts are putting a high CPU load on my servers. I have taken several steps to mitigate this:

- late initialization, using `cached_property` (see [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Cached_Properties) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15393001/647991)), so that only those objects needed are indeed initialized (including `import` of the related modules)
- turning some of my scripts into http services (with a simple `web.py` implementation, wrapping-up my classes). The services are then triggered (by nagios for example), with simple `curl` calls.

This has reduced the load dramatically, going from over 20 CPU load to well under 1. It seems python startup is very resource intensive, for complex programs with lots of inter-dependencies.

I would like to know what other strategies are people here implementing to improve the performance of python software.

Comment: Create C implementations of intensive code and call them from python.

Comment: I do not think my program - by itself - has CPU issues. Those are coming from the python parsing phase.

Answer (score 3):

An easy one-off improvement is to use [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) instead of the standard CPython for long-lived scripts and daemons (for short-lived scripts it's unlikely to help and may actually have longer startup times). Other than that, it sounds like you've already hit upon one of the biggest improvements for short-lived system scripts, which is to avoid the overhead of starting the Python interpreter for frequently-invoked scripts.

For example, if you invoke one script from another and they're both in Python you should definitely consider importing the other script as a module and calling its functions directly, as opposed to using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) or similar.

I appreciate that it's not always possible to do this, since some use-cases rely on external scripts being invoked - Nagios checks, for example, are going to be tricky to keep resident at all times. Your approach of making the actual check script a simple HTTP request seems reasonable enough, but the approach I took was to use [passive checks](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/passivechecks.html) and run an external service to periodically update the status. This allows the service generating check results to be resident as a daemon rather than requiring Nagios to invoke a script for each check.

Also, watch your system to see whether the slowness really is CPU overload or IO issues. You can use utilities like `vmstat` to watch your IO usage. If you're IO bound then optimising your code won't necessarily help a lot. In this case, if you're doing something like processing lots of text files (e.g. log files) then you can store them gzipped and access them directly using Python's [`gzip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) module. This increases CPU load but reduces IO load because you only need transfer the compressed data from disk. You can also write output files directly in gzipped format using the same approach.

I'm afraid I'm not particularly familiar with `web2py` specifically, but you can investigate whether it's easy to put a caching layer in front if the freshness of the data isn't totally critical. Try and make sure both your server and clients use conditional requests correctly, which will reduce request processing time. If they're using a back-end database, you could investigate whether something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) will help. These measures are only likely to give you real benefit if you're experiencing a reasonably high volume of requests or if each request is expensive to handle.

I should also add that generally reducing system load in other ways can occasionally give surprising benefits. I used to have a relatively small server running Apache and I found moving to nginx helped a surprising amount - I believe it was partly more efficient request handling, but primarily it freed up some memory that the filesystem cache could then use to further boost IO-bound operations.

Finally, if overhead is still a problem then carefully profile your most expensive scripts and optimise the hotspots. This could be improving your Python code, or it could mean pushing code out to C extensions if that's an option for you. I've had some great performance by pushing data-path code out into C extensions for large-scale log processing and similar tasks (talking about hundreds of GB of logs at a time). However, this is a heavy-duty and time-consuming approach and should be reserved for the few places where you really need the speed boost. It also depends whether you have someone available who's familiar enough with C to do it.

Comment: Thanks for all these tips. I would say the overhead I see comes mostly from python startup phase (importing dozens of inter-dependent modules), so late initialization is really helping. I do not think my programs have CPU/memory issues - that is, those issues are python interpreter related, not program related. I could squeeze more performance by using C modules, or memcached, but I do not think that would make a big difference (it will once my service is in active use). I am still looking for low-hanging fruit: PyPy is a good candidate. I'll keep the question open for a while for more ideas.

Comment: One thing you could try (which I haven't really experimented with myself) is sticking all the modules (important: include compiled `.pyc` versions as well) in a zip file. See [`zipimport`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) for details. Not sure whether / how much this will help, but it might be worth a shot.